# maintaining wikitext and richtext editing modes in iPad app

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5

I am designing an iPad app in which I have a textView apart from other things. In that textView I am currently rendering wikitext. I have implemented basic functionalities like bold, italic etc. in the editor using accessory view.

---

Now, I want to provide the user an another mode to edit in rich text as well. The rich text editing will be done in the web View (not implemented yet). The problem I am facing is that I don't know a way to keep the text in both the modes in sync so that when a user jumps from one to another he is able to see the changes made in the other mode instantly.
Can someone suggest some clue regarding this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean you have two text views and want to sync text between them?

Comment: The other one will be a webView with its contentEditable set to YES as I have come to know that for rich text editing I will be needing a web view.

Comment: Post the code that you're using to get and render the text from and in the two modes. It sounds like all you should have to do is implement a delegate and pass correctly formatted text.

Comment: I read your question several times and all I see is: "I have two UITextView which do exactly the same". Can explain a little more and provide some code, please?

Comment: @mavrick3: Sorry, for the confusion. I have edited my question now. Hope its clear. Basically the richtext editing needs to be done in a webView so the content in webView and the textView need to be in sync. Moreover webView uses HTML and not the wikitext so I have to make changes to the text in both modes accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's no problem to sync from the `UITextView` to the `UIWebView` using `UITextViewDelegate` to fire events as soon as the User types into the TextView. The bigger problem is the `UIWebView` you'd need to check its source-code to check changes and then sync them to the `UITextView`.

The next best possibility would be to wait on iOS 6 which provides styled text, but iOS 6 is still under NDA, so nobody will provide you help.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer. I just hope someone has something better.